# Equivalent IN operator in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

> var query = from c in context.Albums
>   **where c.AlbumID in albumIds**
>   select c.Albumname;

Here **albumIds is IENUM<>** of some custom type(in my case its an Entity)

When I do the above query I get an error 
Operator == cannot be applied to type int and IEnumerable

This error is acceptable but how do I overcome this

Answer (score 4):

Turn it around slightly - you want to check whether your enumerable of album ids contains the id of an album you have just iterated to in your linq. So something like this ...

```
albumIds = {1,2,13,25,277,567};
var query = context.Albums.Where(x=> albumIds.Contains(x.ID));
```

(Sorry, writing example code without a tool in front of me so forgive any obvious mistakes. Hopefully you can get the idea from this though).

Comment: albumIds is not predefined... **Scenario: I have 3 tables Singer,Album, MasterAlbums.

var query = (from c in context.Singers join d in context.albums on c.SingerID equals d.SignerID into albumIds
select new ()

Now in Albums table I don't have album names I have only ids I need to map Album table to MasterAlbum table to get respective AlbumName..

Comment: In current scneario I get an error .contains is not defined on IENUM<T>

Comment: So if you've defined your entity model with the correct relationships you'll have made `MasterAlbums` a navigation property of an `Albums` entity. This being the case, you can use `.Include("MasterAlbums")` in your linq query to select/bring-back the names of albums. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx for more in-depth info.

Answer (score 1):

```
var albumIds= new string[] { "900", "801", "802", "803","906" };                    
var lstData = context.tbl.Where(
                 x => (x.TimeCreated >= yesterday && x.TimeCreated < today) && 
                 albumIds.Contains(x.TransactionSetId)
               ).Select(x => x.X12_Interchange).ToList();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be very helpful if you used [code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) for readability and provided a brief explanation as to why your answer works.

Comment: Add explanation, please.